# Dll path with "%" in it doesn't register

Tags: dll, root

When I try to register a dll that is in a path, say "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Harsh%\Dllfolder\contextmenu.dll" is fails to register with regsvr32.
If I remove "%" from the path, it registers and works fine.

Why doesn't a path that contains "%" work?
Is there a way to register the dll in such a path?

Thanks,
Harsha

Comment: sorry to ask, but is it related to C++? How are you registering this DLL?

Comment: Yes it's a c++ dll. Am just using the command regsvr32 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Harsh%\Dllfolder\contextmenu.dll to register.

Comment: Did you attempt to escape the % when you called regsvr32? So, I'd wrap the path in quotes: `regsvr32 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Harsh%\Dllfolder\contextmenu.dll"` Also, this is actually not a programming question. There is no code here. You are just calling regsvr32. As such the question belongs on superuser.com. And one final comment. If you use Administrator when developing, then you've no way of detecting standard user bugs in your code. You'll be relying on your users to do that.

Comment: Or perhaps the % needs to be escaped in some other way. I guess the shell is trying to treat it as an environment variable. Perhaps. In fact, I think that should only happen if there are two % signs in your path. How many are there?

Comment: Yes, I did use double quotes. Actually, I created this context menu dll. I had the code to register this in .iss file. And it crashed when one of our testers tried to install it in a folder name with "%" in it. When its installed in any other folder, its registers fine. For testing purpose I took the dll out and registering it manually outside from run

Comment: Works fine here for me with a single %. Still there's no programming here. It's all about how regsvr32 interprets its arguments. Not an SO question.,

Comment: there's only one % in my path. Am actually Windows server (R) 2008.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I really appreciate you taking time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `%foo%` interpolates the content of the environment variable `foo`. I don’t know of any way to escape the percent sign (since when is it valid in pathnames on DOS, anyway?). Your best bid is to forbid them.

Comment: Am sorry, but I see that if a .net dll is placed in such a folder and tried to register with regasm, it gets registered. But, why doesn't it work with regsvr32 c++ dll?

Comment: Probably because the tool interpolates the percent sign itself. It’s not the shell that does these things in Windows®, unlike in Unix.